# Assumption of genus at least $2$ for stable curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces, deformation-theory

In the article "The irreducibility of the space of curves of given genus" by Deligne, Mumford, the definition of stable curves start with the assumption that the genus is at least $2$. Why is this necessary?

Any reference or idea will be very helpful.

Comment: As Dan explains in his answer, the category fibred in groupoids $\mathcal M_1$ is not a Deligne-Mumford stack, as it has positive-dimensional inertia groups. (The automorphism group scheme of a smooth proper genus one curve over $\mathbb C$ contains the curve...) However, there is another more basic (more subtle?) issue. Namely,  the naive definition of  $\mathcal M_1$ does not give a stack, let alone Deligne-Mumford stack.  The point is that "glueing" of smooth proper genus one curves can fail to give a smooth proper genus one curve...

Comment: ... More precisely, descent is not effective for genus one curves; see Raynaud's paper cited in https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04304 . The "correct" definition of $\mathcal M_1$ involves algebraic spaces: For a scheme $S$, the groupoid $\mathcal M_1(S)$ is the groupoid of smooth proper morphisms $X\to S$ of algebraic spaces whose fibres are smooth proper geometrically connected curves of genus one.

Answer (score 5):

In this paper of Deligne and Mumford they define the notion of a *stack*. This is a generalization of the notion of a scheme, introduced to accomodate moduli problems where the objects parametrized have *automorphisms*. For a (non-)example, the Grassmannian is the moduli space parametrizing $k$-dimensional subspaces of a *fixed* vector space $V$; the fact that $V$ is fixed menas that such a subspace has no automorphisms, which explains morally why the moduli space is a scheme in this case. However, curves often do have nontrivial automorphisms, and for this reason the moduli functor of curves is a stack, not a scheme.

The notion of stack introduced in their paper is what's now called a Deligne-Mumford stack. These are the stacks closest to ordinary schemes. The important property of a Deligne-Mumford stack is that the automorphism group of any object is *finite*. Now the automorphism group of a smooth genus $g$ curve is finite if and only if $g \geq 2$, and this is why they make this assumption.

It is common to also consider curves with marked points. These are parametrized by a moduli space $M_{g,n}$. More generally, a curve of genus $g$ with $n$ markings has finite automorphism group if and only if $2g-2+n >0$, and the stacks $M_{g,n}$ are of Deligne-Mumford type if and only if this inequality is satisfied.

There is a more general notion of Artin stack, which accomodates also infinite stabilizer groups. If you don't mind working with Artin stacks then the moduli spaces $M_{g,n}$ for $2g-2+n \leq 0$ are perfectly sensible objects to consider, too.